# Consistent way of doing paired-trial validation (and leave-one-dataset-out validation)

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, dataset, validation

In *paired-trial validation*, a statistical (ML) models are  trained on $n$ datasets separately and then applied to other datasets, as a way of estimating the generalization of the models obtained. Typically, when training a model on a single dataset, we would separate the dataset in a train and test sets, so that we can test the model on the data coming from the same source. In case of paired-trial validation this leaves us with possibility of splitting every dataset into train and test parts, and testing the models only on the test parts of the other datasets, or testing on the full datasets, and even training on full datasets.

I wonder what is the consistent way of doing it - i.e., what potential pitfalls or typical errors one should avoid.

Similar questions arise in the context of the *leave-one-dataset-out* approach, where the model is trained on all the datasets except one, and then applied to the dataset withheld.

Suggestions for solid background reading on the subject would be greatly appreciated as well.